# Как получить информацию о версии Unreal'а, имея только uasset файлы

Tags: разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine

Есть на руках несколько файлов формата .uasset. В них есть очень качественные модельки, которые я хочу сп.... позаимствовать для проекта. Есть какие то способы узнать версию unreal'а? Мой 4.27.2 отказывается даже видеть эти файлы, хотя я его уже битый день в них тыкаю!